# Monitoring my own activity on computer?

Tags: windows, monitoring

I'd like to have good statistics of how much time I spend doing various tasks on my computer (I'm using Windows Vista), so I'm looking for a good tool for that. It has to monitor what application I am using, and in the case of browsing, what websites I visit (in Firefox).

Additional features I'd like to see are grouping (e.g. `slashdot.org` and `reader.google.com` under "Web surfing") and exporting data (so I can analyze them on my own, if I want to).

What would you recommend for this task?

Answer (score 10):

[ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) is what you need.

Comment: +1 ManicTime is good and not data-greedy.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) to [rescuetime](http://www.rescuetime.com/), because it doesn't send all your usage statistics to its server, as rescuetime does.

Answer (score 2):

[rescuetime](http://www.rescuetime.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Wakoopa](http://wakoopa.com/) to track usage patterns.