# Looking for simple Windows monitoring software (so I know how much time I spend working vs. surfing)

Tags: windows, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitoring my own activity on computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/72221/monitoring-my-own-activity-on-computer)

I am looking for something free, maybe with a report at the end of each day that tells me how much time I spend on different sites.

I don't want something that logs keystrokes, blocks websites, or takes screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

What browser do you use? There are browser extensions, addons, and plugins that provide this function.

There are [extensions for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search?category=ext&q=track%20time).

There are [addons for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=track%20time).

There are [extensions for Opera](https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/).

There *should*  be [plugins for IE](http://www.ieaddons.com/ca/addons/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try http://manictime.com/

> Manictime sits in the background and records your activities, so you can just forget it is there and focus on your work. When you are finished you can use collected data to accurately keep track of your time.