# Is there a good application to monitor my activities on my computer and give reports about?

Tags: windows-7, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitoring my own activity on computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/72221/monitoring-my-own-activity-on-computer)

I was using www.rescuetime.com to for this purpose, but I am asking if there is any other application there which do something like what rescuetime is doing.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on what kind of activities you want to track? Programs, documents? Amount of typing, mouse usage? How did RescueTime fail to meet your expectations? Anything a tiny bit more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question: [Monitoring my own activity on computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/72221/monitoring-my-own-activity-on-computer) It looks like you want [Manic Time](http://www.manictime.com/) although the free version doesn't have all the advanced stuff as the pro version ($67). The free should be enough. It doesn't send your usage to a server like Rescue Time.