# Application that automatically tracks amount of active time spent at the computer

Tags: windows, software-rec, time-management

I'm looking for an application that keeps track of the total amount of time spent at the computer. It doesn't have to (and can't be) very precise.

If it doesn't seen any mouse/keyboard activity in 5 minutes it can assume I'm no longer at the computer.

I *don't need and don't want* to track on which applications I spent the time on. I really want something super simple, but surprisingly enough all the applications that I found do too much.

Comment: Perhaps list (provide links even) for some of the ones you've already tried, so people can avoid giving you those as an answer. Also providing your desired version and edition of Windows may help.

Comment: Related: [Application that tracks amount of time spent at the computer](http://superuser.com/questions/72221/monitoring-my-own-activity-on-computer), etc. Not sure how "Automatic" the many choices are, so I'm not going to mark it as a dupe.

Comment: If you interestes i can make you a quick app in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this site : http://marmot.gruk.org/
Their software is called The Turtle.
There is a whole community and people track how far they've moved their mouse, how much keys did you hit on your keayboard, and of course it tracks the total uptime of your machine, and the total use time of your machine.
You can edit your preferences like how long to wait before considering you as "away".
It's running in the backgroud, and it is not annoying.